# Excel how to calculate percentage

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel 2003/2007

```
name, count
a, 3
b, 4
c, 9
...
```

Say I have data like this, is there a built-in function that can automatically count percentage for each row? (ie. a = (3/(3+4+9)) = 18.75%). Also the data will be added continuously. Can I know solutions for both Excel 2003 & 2007. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel *Lists* will help you here.

- Convert your range to a List and add a Totals Row (sum)
- Insert an extra column to the list called Percentages and define the calulation for the first row ( = this row's count / the cell containing the total)
- To add new rows, drag the list handle (bottom right) and add new data.

These instructions apply to Excel 2007 and 2010. Excel 2003 also supports Lists but without as much functionality as the later versions, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you could also just make a total at the bottom, and calculate this for each row (just fill down): =[current row's calculated number]/[total]. just replace those two values and for the total field make it look like this $B$2 (or $G$5)

this is much simpler than making a list, although lists still work nicer.